# Finding non-integer in a string

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to error check command line arguments to make sure they are integers, and surprisingly having a difficult time doing so. Here is a snippet of code I have that works when all the command line arguments are integers.

Program can have infinite values passed into it.
One example: `./program -p 45 67 3 9 1`

```
for (argCounter = 2; argCounter < argc; argCounter++) 
{
    total = total * atoi(argv[argCounter]);
}
```

What happens when a user types `5g`? `atoi()` converts it to 5. I need to it to return an error. For some reason I was having trouble getting `isdigit()` to work properly as well. I tried so many random things that my head is spinning at this point. So what I'm trying to do is:

```
    for (argCounter = 2; argCounter < argc; argCounter++) 
    {
        //pseudocode
        if (argv[argCounter] != integer)
        {
              printf("Error!");
              return 0;
        } 

        total = total * atoi(argv[argCounter]);
    }
```

Comment: Is your question "how can I check if every character in a string is a digit?". Your documentation for `strol` probably explains how to check if the entire string was a valid integer. (See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html), if `*endptr==0` after the call, the entire string was parsed.)

Comment: blindside044 Please not not comment with an uninformative "did not work" in 2 places below.  Better to state input used, output seen and output expected.  Even better, this question should have had a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sscanf()`. Its `%n` placeholder can be used to determine the number of characters consumed, which you can compare to the string length:

```c
for (argCounter = 2; argCounter < argc; argCounter++) 
{
    int value, consumed;

    if ((sscanf(argv[argCounter], "%d%n", &value, &consumed) != 1) ||
        (argv[argCounter][consumed] != '\0'))
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    } 

    total *= value;
}
```

Or, you can use `strtol()`. It can output a pointer to the first unparsed character. You can check to see if that character is a null terminator or not:

```c
for (argCounter = 2; argCounter < argc; argCounter++) 
{
    char *end;

    errno = 0;
    long value = strtol(argv[argCounter], &end, 10);

    if ((end == argv[argCounter]) ||
        (*end != '\0') ||
        (((value == LONG_MIN) || (value == LONG_MAX)) && (errno == ERANGE)))
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    } 

    total *= value;
}
```

Comment: The first solution did not work, but the second one using strtol() did. Thank you. Now to figure out how/why it worked because copy/paste does me no good =D  .....i remember attempting to use strtol() at one point but the function confused me a bit, so I had no idea what I was doing.

Comment: @blindside044 "*The first solution did not work*" - [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/gWOr6I)

Comment: On a minor note: I find `"%d %n"` with a space a nicer more forgiving format as it allows trailing spaces to pass - not that trailing nor leading spaces are commonly encountered with program arguments.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica “*not that trailing nor leading spaces are commonly encountered with program arguments*” - they shouldn’t be at all, except maybe in quoted arguments.

Comment: True, they can occur due to quoted arguments, calls to `main()` (yeech) and `exec()`-like calls.  Good answer anyway - just noting a potential extension.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm quite a beginner and I don't exactly understand what you want to do exactly?
if I understand, you want to check if all arguments are numbers (only digits) included in the integer range you want that total contain the produce of the multiplication of all these integers (and I assume you also want total to be in integer range?)

```
long long total = 1;
for (argCounter = 1; argCounter < argc; argCounter++) 
{
    char *check_end;
    long long nbr = stroll(arg[argCounter], &check_end, 10);
    if (!argv[argCounter][0]|| *check_end || nbr > INT_MAX || nbr < INT_MIN || nbr * total > INT_MAX || nbr * total < INT_MIN)
    {
        total = 0;
        printf("Error\n");
        break;
    }
    total *= nbr;
}
```

maybe this should help, stroll convert a string (given as first parameter) in a base(given as third parameter) to a `long long`  and set the string's pointer (given as second parameter) to the place on the string where the conversion stopped (`\0` if only digits after the sign) you could check the stroll man; anyway im not sure my code is very optimised or functional and you may want to get an int at the end so cast as int total variable to an int variable.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work. Remy's second solution seemed to do the trick for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Note: OP's code starts at `argCounter = 2;`

Comment: Curious, why does code use `long long` vs `long` and then compare against `INT_MAX, INT_MIN`?    Also `nbr * total` can readily overflow resulting in undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: well , yea soz im a beginner and tried to purpose something which would maximise the chance to detect an INT overflow given what i supposed that blindside wanted, anyway yea it still can overflow i guess (INT_MAX * INT_MAX is surely greater thant long long max value. sorry for my noobness